# Mocking nested properties with mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, properties, mocking, nested

I have a function call that returns an object:

```
r = Foo(x,y)
```

where `r` has a rich set of nested properties. For example, I can access `r.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c`. I would like to mock `Foo`, such that a specific leaf property of `r` is modified, i.e. such that `r.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c` returns a value under my control:

```
>> r = Foo(x,y)
>> r.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c
'fish'
>> # some mock magic patching of Foo is taking place here
>> r = Foo(x,y)
>> r.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c
'my_fish'
```

I do not care about intermediate properties much.

**Is there an elegant way to mock nested properties with [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html)?**

Comment: It may very well be that certain things are left the way they are. Ended up using the real thing instead of mock.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Replace the mock object's attribute call as you would expect:

```
>> r1 = r_original(x, y)
>> r1.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c
'fish'

>> returner = mock.MagicMock()
>> returner.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c = 'fish'
>> r_mocked = mock.MagicMock(spec_set=r_original, return_value=returner)
>> r2 = r_mocked(x, y)
>> r2.prop_a.prop_b
MagicMock name='returner.prop_a.prop_b' id='87412560'>
>> r2.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c
'fish'
```

This allows you the full power of mocking while defining a specific value.

Comment: Is r2 an instance of r_original class?

Comment: No, it is a MagicMock object.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, because I was using `Mock` instead of `MagicMock` for this.   `r2.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c` was never `'fish'`, it was being generated as `Mock` instance instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to expose the original properties elsewhere, you can define a wrapper class:

```
class OverrideAttributePath(object):
    """A proxy class where we override a specific attribute path with the
    value given. For any other attribute path, we just return
    attributes on the wrapped object.

    """
    def __init__(self, thing, path, value):
        self._thing = thing
        self._path = path
        self._value = value

    def __dir__(self):
        return dir(self._thing)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._thing)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self._path == [index]:
            return self._value
        elif self._path[0] == index:
            return OverrideAttributePath(
                self._thing[index], self._path[1:], self._value)
        else:
            return self._thing[index]

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if self._path == [key]:
            return self._value
        elif self._path[0] == key:
            return OverrideAttributePath(
                getattr(self._thing, key), self._path[1:], self._value)
        else:
            return getattr(self._thing, key)
```

Usage is then as follows:

```
>>> r = Foo(x,y)
>>> r2 = OverrideAttributePath(r, ['prop_a', 'prop_b', 'prop_c'], 'my_fish')
>>> r2.prop_a.prop_b.prop_c
'my_fish'
```