# How can I mock object with nested attributes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def is_room_member(invitee, msg):
        return invitee in msg.frm.room.occupants
```

I want to test the method `is_room_member` where `invitee` is a string and
`occupants` is a list of string.

If `invitee = 'batman'` and `occupants = ['batman', 'superman']` the method `is_room_member` returns `True`.

`msg` is the object which needs to be mocked so that I can test this method.

How can I test this method, since it'll require this `msg` object which has nested attributes?

I want the test to be something like:

```
class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_is_room_member(self):
        occupants = ['batman', 'superman']
        # mocking 
        # msg = MagicMock()
        # msg.frm.room.occupants = occupants
        self.assertTrue(Foo.is_room_member('batman', msg))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an existing answer for your question:
[Mocking nested properties with mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978945/mocking-nested-properties-with-mock)

```
import unittest
import mock

class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def is_room_member(invitee, msg):
        return invitee in msg.frm.room.occupants

class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_is_room_member(self):
        occupants = ['batman', 'superman']

        # mocking
        mocked_msg = mock.MagicMock()
        mocked_msg.frm.room.occupants = occupants

        self.assertTrue(Foo.is_room_member('batman', mocked_msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MagicMock is so magical...it is exactly what you wrote.

```
class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_is_room_member(self):
    occupants = ['batman', 'superman']
    msg = MagicMock()
    msg.frm.room.occupants = occupants
    print(msg.frm.room.occupants) # >>> ['batman', 'superman']
    self.assertTrue(Foo.is_room_member('batman', msg))
```

From the [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide):

> Mock and MagicMock objects create all attributes and methods as you access them and store details of how they have been used.

Unless you say otherwise, everything returns a MagicMock!